# Differentiability conditions for a piecewise function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, continuity

[image]

So this is an analysis class, and we just started the unit on differentiability -- however I missed the class. Can someone start me off with a good real analysis definition for differentiability of a function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function $f: \mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is said to be differentiable at a point $x_0$ if $$\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0}{\frac{f(x_0)-f(x)}{x-x_0}}$$ exists, and when the limit exists, we call the limit $f'(x_0)$.  Another way it is typically presented is as $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}{\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}}$, but this is the same as the above definition by simply letting $h=x_0-x$.

For limits of real-valued functions of a real variable (i.e. $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$), the limit exists if and only if both one-sided limits exist and are equal.

Thus, for the purposes of the problem you presented, you need to find the derivative of each of 'piece' of the piecewise function and then take the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ of the resulting derivative to make sure they agree.  For your specific problem, the derivative of 0 is 0, and the derivative of $|x|^\alpha \sin(1/x)$ is $(x^2)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}-1} \left[ \alpha x\sin \frac{1}{x} - \cos \frac{1}{x}\right]$.  For what $\alpha$ does the limit as $x\rightarrow 0$ equal 0?

Comment: Thanks for this! Glad to see it's the good ol difference quotient i'm familiar with. 

Am I essentially solving $(x^2)^{\frac{\alpha}{2}-1} \left[ \alpha x\sin \frac{1}{x} - \cos \frac{1}{x}\right] = 0 $ for alpha? or finding alpha that make this zero?

Comment: I believe I was wrong. I'm just trying to reason about the difference quotient limit with the original piecewise now, although it's quite a bit harder than I'd imagined. do you have any tips?